# Anaconda Sudo PIP permissions Problems

Tags: python, anaconda

I'm learning Python and have Anaconda installed, and I'm trying to familiarize myself with the process of getting an [Eye-Color Detection project working](https://github.com/ghimiredhikura/Eye-Color-Detection).
I'm running into the following error after going through readme:

`Eye-Color-Detection git:(master) ✗ sudo pip install -r requirements.txt`

```
WARNING: The directory '/Users/{user}/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned or is not writable by the current user. The cache has been disabled. Check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

When trying to update:

`(tweet) ➜  Eye-Color-Detection git:(master) ✗ conda update --all`

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Users/{user}/opt/anaconda3/envs/tweet/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wrapt/__init__.py' -> '/Users/{user}/opt/anaconda3/envs/tweet/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wrapt/__init__.py.c~'
```

**Q: How might I go about doing this correctly within the same Conda environment?**

Comment: Could you please mention your operating system and the conda and python versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the time, a `sudo pip install` is almost never what you really want. While in some cases, it may "appear" to work and solve you're immediate problem. More often than not you've just broken your system python without knowing it.

In the context of that repo, I'd ignore the repo's README and do this.

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ghimiredhikura/Eye-Color-Detection
$ cd Eye-Color-Detection
```

Create a virtualenv environment, change `yourenvname` as you like.

```
$ conda create -n yourenvname python=3.x
$ conda activate yourenvname
```

Install the dependencies and run the code

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
$ python3 eye-color.py --input_path=sample/2.jpg --input_type=ima
```

As fixing you conda environment may be difficult to debug depending on what else you've `sudo`'d in attempting to resolve your issue. If you happen to be familiar with "regular" virtualenv's created using python's builtin virtual environment tooling, then you could also try this to get you going.

```
$ python3 -m venv .venv --copies
$ source .venv/bin/active

$ pip install -r requirements.txt

$ python3 eye-color.py --input_path=sample/2.jpg --input_type=image
```

Comment: Creating the new environment worked like an absolute charm.  This is what I'll do for any similarly installed packages in the future. TY!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is you have to change the directory premission to `writable`.

You can do it using this command,

```sh
$ sudo chmod 7777 /Users/{user}/library/caches/
```

to change permissions recursively,

```sh
$ sudo chmod 7777 -R /Users/{user}/library/caches/
```

or you can own that directory by using this command,

```sh
$ sudo chown OWNER:GROUP /Users/{user}/library/caches/
```

where `OWNER` is the username for your computer which you can find in the terminal by using this command.

```sh
$ whoami
```

`GROUP` is optional.